# Forcing an HTML input to be closed, using jQuery or built-in JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html

I'm dynamically generating some HTML inputs using jQuery, i.e :

```
var $node = $('<input />')
    .addClass('blabla')
    .attr('type', 'text')
    .attr('readonly', true)
    Etc...
```

Then I'm using the .NET XML API to parse that HTML. THe problem is that, jQuery (or the browser, I don't know) is generating an unclosed input tag. While this is valid HTML5, the .NET XML API fails to parse it as valid XML.

So my question is : how can I get jQuery (or the browser) to generate a self-closing input tag ? I mean in a clean way, not by replacing/inserting into the generated string. Thanks !

Sorry if such a question already exists, but I failed to find it.

Comment: html != xml as far as i know

Comment: i think you need a .NET HTML parser

Comment: Let's just say I want to make sure that I generate a subset of HTML that is also valid XML.

Comment: You're generating a DOM. You aren't generating HTML at all.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that I am serializing this into HTML using the outerHTML property of the node. That was obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a valid XHTML stringification of your Document, or part of it, then you can simply use an [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLSerializer):

```js
console.log(
  (new XMLSerializer)
    .serializeToString(test)
);
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <input><br><img>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.